# How to use while read line to print filename into each line of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, while-loop, readline

In a folder I have the following text files:

```
$ ls
listofdirectories
CTCF_BEDfiles EZH2_BEDfiles H2AFZ_BEDfiles ... +30 or so more *BEDfiles
```

What I am trying to do is pipe each line of `listofdirectories` into an awk print function to change all of the lines in `*BEDfiles` from just the BEDfile name to the directory I wish to store it in.
(*BEDfiles are all compressed text files)

```
$ cat listofdirectories
CTCF_assay
EZH2_assay
H2AFZ_assay
... etc.

$ zcat CTCF_BEDfiles
ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz
ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz
ENCFF490CTJ.bed.gz
... etc.
```

I have a directory for each line of `listofdirectories` `e.g., ~/folder/CTCF_assay`, and wish to convert each line of each text file `*BEDfiles` into a pathway to store the BEDfile in its appropriate folder. All new directory lines can be stored in a single text file `pathsforBEDfiles`

```
Desired Outcome:
$ cat pathsforBEDfiles
~/folder/CTCF_assay/ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz
~/folder/CTCF_assay/ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz
~/folder/CTCF_assay/ENCFF490CTJ.bed.gz
... etc.
```

I have tried the following:

```
$ cat listofdirectories | while read line ; do zcat "${line%assay}BEDfiles" | awk '{print "~/folder/"$line"/"$0"/"}'; done > pathsforBEDfiles
```

This nearly worked for me, but the "$line" in the awk command is printing out lines from `*BEDfiles` rather than lines from `listofdirectories`.

```
What the above code returns (viewed with less -S)

~/folder/ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz/ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz/
~/folder/ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz/ENCFF509KKI.bed.gz/
~/folder/ENCFF490CTJ.bed.gz/ENCFF490CTJ.bed.gz/
... etc.
```

Any idea how I can get the `$line` in the awk command to print `*_assay`  from `listofdirectories` instead of `ENCFF*` from `*BEDfiles`?

Thanks, Steven

Answer (score 2):

As written the current script is unable to access the `bash` variable `$line`.

In `awk` this - `$line` - is a field reference where the number of the field is whatever value is stored in the `awk` variable `line`; but since `line` is never defined it defaults to a value of `0`, leaving us with the reference to `$0`, which is how we reference the entire line of input; this in turn means OP's current `awk/print` is doing the following:

```
print "~/folder/" $0 "/" $0 "/"
```

Hence the reason we're seeing the contents from the `zcat'd` file echoed twice in the output.

---

One idea for updating OP's current code:

```
while read -r line
do
    zcat "${line%assay}BEDfiles" | awk -v line="${line}" '{print "~/folder/" line "/" $0 "/"}'
done < listofdirectories > pathsforBEDfiles
```

Comment: updated code works a charm! Thanks for the help - I felt like I was trying to brute force my way into making my version work, yours is much cleaner